# Lightning Messaging Service: sforce.one not defined

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

I am using Lightning message service to pass message from VF page to LWC. VF page is in iframe and I am using this method to publish message
`sforce.one.publish(CHANNEL, message);`

However I am getting sforce.one is undefined error.
Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [well-documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/message_channel_considerations.htm) use case that will not work for LMS. Exposing `sforce` in an iframed visualforce can lead to Security issues.

From the Docs

> Lightning Message Service does not work in Visualforce pages that are included in Lightning Experience via iframes, including wave:dashboard, apex:iframe, and the standard HTML  tag. Instead, add Visualforce pages through the Lightning App Builder or as a utility bar item.

Comment: Thanks Mohith! I seem to have missed that part of documentation.